# Conflict with Natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

I am currently writing my thesis and I've ran into a problem while increasing the complexity of the packages I needed to use. I was originally using the `\cite{}` macro to do all the references but I needed some more functionality hence I opted for the `natbib` package. Unfortunately when I try to compile the tex file I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty:739: LaTeX Error: Command \citetext already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

￼l.739 ...ommand\citetext[1]{\NAT@open#1\NAT@close}
```

I think that the `natbib` package might be conflicting with another package that already defines the `\citetext` key, but how can I tell? I've tried a process of elimination but wasn't able to track down the offending package - if it even is that case - .
The packages are imported into the main tex file with `\input{packages}` and include:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Declare packages %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{ccaption, graphicx, textcomp, tabularx, booktabs, longtable, rotating, lscape}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg, .eps, .png}


\usepackage{enumerate,latexsym,amsmath,amssymb, amsthm, algorithm, algorithmic, verbatim}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

% Use of & in the acronyms
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Acronyms %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym} 

\newcommand{\listofacronymsname}{Acronyms}

\newcommand{\listofacronyms}{%
\chapter*{\listofacronymsname}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listofacronymsname}%
\label{sec:acronyms}%
\markboth{\listofacronymsname}{\listofacronymsname}%
}


\usepackage[authoryear,round, nonamebreak]{natbib}

% Reference which pages the citation was referenced in
\usepackage[pagebackref, breaklinks]{hyperref} 
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{[pp. #1]}
```

Can anyone think of any reason why this error might be coming up? I'm really stumped here.
Please let me know if you need any more information. I know this is a bit skim, but the thesis is quite large at this point and I'm not sure what would be of help or not.

Cheers,
Christos

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you've only recently switched from another citation management package (which may define the `\citetext` macro in a way that's incompatible with `natbib`'s definition) to `natbib`, you may well come across some puzzling error messages. Try wiping out the `.aux` (and all other auxiliary) files and then rerunning latex/bibtex/latex/latex.

Comment: Hey Mico, thanks for the reply. I should also mention the setup I'm currently working with, as it is important. I'm working on OSX with TeX Live installed, and Latexian as the editor. What Latexian does is generate temporary files for a live preview every time. Which means that a new aux file is generated as well.